# Get Access Token Azure AD using client certificate with Golang

Tags: azure, go, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

**I am trying to do the modern authentication from azure ad with client certificate.**
The process says.

1. Create an azure application.
2. Upload the certificate to azure application and get the thumbprint.
3. Generate the JWT token using that certificate(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials)
4. Then use that jwt-token to get the access-token.
5. To get the access-token, call an API (https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token)
6. The HTTP method is of type *POST* and post body data will be *x-www-form-urlencoded*

After doing all the steps when i try to get the token.
I get this error.

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client",
    "error_description": "AADSTS700023: Client assertion audience claim does not match Realm issuer. Review the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials .\r\nTrace ID: 714b5009-b74d-46b5-bd0e-3bea76272a01\r\nCorrelation ID: 2cb703bb-f325-44b5-a669-605bc7a81ac0\r\nTimestamp: 2020-08-28 07:31:19Z",
    "error_codes": [
        700023
    ],
    "timestamp": "2020-08-28 07:31:19Z",
    "trace_id": "714b5009-b74d-46b5-bd0e-3bea76272a01",
    "correlation_id": "2cb703bb-f325-44b5-a669-605bc7a81ac0"
}
```

I am generating the JWT token using go code and parsing the PFX file.

```
func getAuthJWTToken() (string, error) {
    clientID := "**********************"
    _tenantName := "******************"
    pfxFilePath := `E:\abcd.pfx`
    certPassword := `*********`
    authToken := ""
    pfxFile, err := os.Open(pfxFilePath)

    if err != nil {
        return authToken, err
    }

    pfxfileinfo, _ := pfxFile.Stat()

    var size int64 = pfxfileinfo.Size()

    pfxbytes := make([]byte, size)
    buffer := bufio.NewReader(pfxFile)
    _, err = buffer.Read(pfxbytes)

    //PFX to PEM for computation of signature
    var pembytes []byte
    blocks, err := pkcs12.ToPEM(pfxbytes, certPassword)

    for _, b := range blocks {
        pembytes = append(pembytes, pem.EncodeToMemory(b)...)
    }

    //Decoding the certificate contents from pfxbytes
    pk, cert, err := pkcs12.Decode(pfxbytes, certPassword)
    if cert == nil {
        fmt.Printf("Bye")
        return authToken, nil
    }
    if pk == nil {

    }

    pfxFile.Close() // close file

    notToBeUsedBefore := time.Now()
    expirationTime := time.Now().Add(3000 * time.Minute)
    URL := fmt.Sprintf("https://login.microsoftonline.com/%s/oauth2/token", _tenantName)

    id := guid.New()

    claims := &claims{
        StandardClaims: jwt.StandardClaims{
            // In JWT, the expiry time is expressed as unix milliseconds
            ExpiresAt: expirationTime.Unix(),
            Audience:  URL,
            Issuer:    clientID, // consumer key of the connected app, hardcoded
            NotBefore: notToBeUsedBefore.Unix(),
            Subject:   clientID,
            Id:        id.String(),
        },
    }

    //token_header    map[string]interface{}

    token := jwt.NewWithClaims(jwt.SigningMethodRS256, claims)

    sha1Fingerprint := sha1.Sum(cert.Raw)
    var slice []byte
    slice = sha1Fingerprint[:]
    b64FingerPrint := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(slice))
    token.Header["x5t"] = b64FingerPrint

    signKey, err := jwt.ParseRSAPrivateKeyFromPEM(pembytes) // parse the RSA key

    tokenString, err := token.SignedString(signKey) // sign the claims with private key

    fmt.Printf(fmt.Sprintf("JWT token is %s", tokenString))

    return tokenString, err
}
```

I need the help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#first-case-access-token-request-with-a-shared-secret?

Comment: Yes i am refereeing to the same document.


```POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1               // Line breaks for clarity
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_id=97e0a5b7-d745-40b6-94fe-5f77d35c6e05
&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer
&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Imd4OHRHeXN5amNScUtqRlBuZDdSRnd2d1pJMCJ9.eyJ{a lot of characters here}M8U3bSUKKJDEg
&grant_type=client_credentials```

Comment: Please add the decode of your `client_assertion` in your issue.

Comment: @PamelaPeng are you asking for the jwt token string ?
I didn't get that question, can you explain more on it.

Comment: The decoded string of your `client_assertion`. You could decode it with https://jwt.io/.

Comment: That contains some sensitive information.

Comment: You could remove the sensitive information. I want the `aud` in your `client_assertion`.